# PostgreSQL Trigger for update master table when relation table has rows deleted or added. Using "FOR EACH STATEMENT"

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have some people

[image]

I have some cars to choose from

[image]

And I have the relations for "Person has cars"

[image]

I want a trigger that updates the "lastmod" for a person when he changes his car-pool

```
CREATE TRIGGER people_stamp
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON people_car_rel
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE people_stamp_func();
```

It is of course a STATEMENT trigger.

And then the problematic function:
(the `people_car_rel.pid` is not available inside the function ????)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION people_stamp_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
begin
    UPDATE people set lastmod = now() where people.pid = people_car_rel.pid;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

And some SQL to test:

```
delete from people_car_rel
where pid = 'ja';

drop table if exists updates;
CREATE TEMP TABLE updates (p varchar, c varchar);
INSERT INTO updates (p, c) VALUES ('ja','v');
INSERT INTO updates (p, c) VALUES ('ja','f');

INSERT INTO people_car_rel (pid, cid)
select p, c from updates;    
select * from t_carowners_rel_cars_cb;
```

How to solve this ? Any suggestions ?

Second try (after advice):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION people_stamp_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
begin
  IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    UPDATE people set lastmod = now() from (select distinct pid from new_table) as nw
      where people.pid = nw.pid;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    UPDATE people set lastmod = now() from (select distinct pid from old_table) as od
      where people.pid = od.pid;
  END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER people_stamp_ins
AFTER INSERT ON people_car_rel
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION people_stamp_func();

CREATE TRIGGER people_stamp_del
AFTER DELETE ON people_car_rel
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION people_stamp_func();
```

I get the error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "new_table" does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function people_stamp_func() line 4 at SQL statement
```

Final result - This one works :-)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION people_stamp_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
begin
  IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    UPDATE people set lastmod = now() from (select distinct pid from old_table) as od
      where people.pid = od.pid;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    UPDATE people set lastmod = now() from (select distinct pid from new_table) as nw
      where people.pid = nw.pid;
  END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER people_stamp_ins
AFTER INSERT ON people_car_rel
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION people_stamp_func();

CREATE TRIGGER people_stamp_del
AFTER DELETE ON people_car_rel
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION people_stamp_func();
```

Comment: You need `for each row` trigger instead of `for each statement`. But if you want to use `for each statement` - there are `REFERENCING OLD/NEW TABLE AS ...` parameters in the `create trigger` statement, see example [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE)

Comment: If the relation table has 100 cars for one person, it feels wrong to update by row. I'm sure someone will come up with a good solution... I consider my question to be quite generel...
BTW: The example you gave... I can't see that it should be a solution. I does not show how I can use the "pid" in play inside the function ?

Comment: In the example `new_table` contains inserted rows from the trigger's target table. For your case in the trigger function `select distinct pid from new_table` will return all distinct pids from the inserted data. Read the documentation.

Comment: I have updated the post after your advice, but... :-(

Comment: For `DELETE` operation use `old_table`and for `INSERT` use `new_table` in the function :)

Comment: Augh !!! My mistake. I works like a charm now. Thank you so much. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: Congrats! Post your final result as an answer for other readers.